# Update view angular array push

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to handle the push update in Angular in the view but it has been impossible for me. I know the following:

I have an array, this array is called **marca1** and it receives all the objects that the get request that I make to the server and it shows in the view with **ng-repeat**.

When I send the post request to save a new data, it gets a response from the server that I save it in an object called **pepa**.

I use the push function for my fix to refresh the view, but that does not work.

Why can it be failing? How can I fix it?

**This is my code:**

```
miAppAngular.controller('marca',function($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams,configuracionGlobal){

  $scope.config = configuracionGlobal;
  $scope.marca1=[];

  $http.get( configuracionGlobal.api_url + "/marca/listaMarca.php")
    .then( function(respuesta){
    $scope.marca1=respuesta.data;
  });

  $scope.nuevaMarca = function ( ){  
    $scope.newMarca={
      'nombre':$scope.nombreMarca
    }

    $scope.pepa={};
    //     
    $http({
      url: configuracionGlobal.api_url + "/marca/nuevaMarca.php",  
      method: "POST",
      data: $scope.newMarca,   
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
      .then(
      function(respuesta){
        $scope.pepa= respuesta;
        $scope.marca1.push($scope.pepa);

        $('#modalMarca').modal('hide');
      }
    )         
  }
```

Comment: can you `console.log(respuesta)` in the POST success function and see if you need to drill down 1 more level ?

Comment: console.log(respuesta)Objectconfig: Objectdata: Objectnombre: "p22"__proto__: Objectheaders: Objectmethod: "POST"paramSerializer: (a)transformRequest: Array[1]transformResponse: Array[1]url: "http://localhost/jcreparaciones/api/marca/nuevaMarca.php"__proto__: Objectdata: "ok  
↵"headers: (d)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object

Comment: actual data returned possibly in `respuesta.data`.

Comment: response ''ok''

Answer (score 0):

Try to run getMarca after posting:

```
$scope.getMarca = function() {
$http.get( configuracionGlobal.api_url + "/marca/listaMarca.php")

.then(function(respuesta)
{
    $scope.marca1=respuesta.data;
});
}
```

In your .then() of your post, at the end call: `$scope.getMarca()`

This shall update the array $scope.marca1.

The response returned after a POST is usually used for checking; whether it was a success or failure (or to return custom values from backend).

Comment: If you look from the console the call is done correctly to the function and brings the new value but still does not update the view

Comment: In the .then() of your post, what is the response/respuesta?

Comment: If it is "ok" only, then you are pushing "ok" into $scope.marca1.

Comment: In the console I can see the value that enters the array but the problem is that the view does not update the new information

Comment: The code line $ scope.marca1.push ($ scope.newMarca); It works and updates my view, but if that same code I do with modal bootstrap does not work does not update the view

Comment: Post a working link (from codepen or otherwise). I shall inspect it individually.